# REST API - How to check whether a user's email id is currently active?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

How can I find a user who has access to my SharePoint site is active? Sometimes, a user may delete his/her email id.  I want to find out a user who uses my SharePoint Site is still active and doesn't deleted his/her account using API.  How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about external users, or users within your tenant AAD?

Comment: Both the external users and the users within my tenant AAD